# Rich text editor fails when pasting in IE 8 and 9 error 800a025e

Tags: javascript, richhtmlfield, copy-and-paste

We have a solution with a lot of customization. At some point something was added that breaks the rich text editor because now I cannot paste from clipboard using either Ctrl+V or the "Paste" ribbon button.

When I try to paste I get this error:

> Could not complete the operation due to error 800a025e

Does anyone know what it means in this context and how I may go about fixing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharePoint rich text fields support copy & paste by using an `iframe` dynamically inserted into the body tag. Manipulating this iframe or any of its content may cause error 800a025e thrown by `SP.UI.RTE.debug.js`.

Searching through `SP.UI.RTE.debug.js` for "pasteDiv" should help you debugging this issue, as the inserted iframe contains a DIV with id "pasteDiv".

I was able to recreate your error by manipulating the inserted iframe (setting display: none in css).

Comment: It seems the error was caused by setting body > iframe {display: none;} as you said. Removing the declaration fixed the issue.